# Is there a Physics textbook that builds on the historical development of Physics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, history

Context: I plan to go back to university to study Physics just for fun in a few years, when kid is older and we have more $$. I have studied some Physics in university 10+ years ago but forget most.

So I stumbled upon [this webpage](https://beforenewton.blog/earth/october-2-galileos-physics/) and it fascinates me by going into the details of history. It doesn't list formulas (sadly) but focuses on 1) What theory did Galileo try to prove or disprove, 2) What was his thought process, 3) How did he reach his arguments.

I think knowing all these gives me a lot of contexts and more importantly hints at Physics intuition. Galileo was not trying to derive some formulas -- he had a lot of observation of the world and was trying to explain it with a model. I think it's a lot more important to follow his thought process, or at least it is more fun.

Do we have a Physics textbook that not only lists formulas and their derivations/applications but also the above? I'm OK if it only deals with Classical Mechanics but would love to see other topics covered if possible. I'm OK with heavy Math too.

Comment: So, you want an introductory textbook for classical mechanics and perhaps other topics in classical physics that follows a historical approach? Not a textbook, though you might find Weinberg's 'To Explain the World' interesting

Comment: @innisfree thanks! Yeah exactly what you described. I'll take a look of Weinberg tomorrow.

Comment: I feel as though this is a missing niche here, which is a shame because there can be genuinely valuable information that is glossed over and missed.

Comment: Hi Nicholas Humphrey, to reopen this post (v2), consider to focus the title question.

Comment: For the modern physics you might like to check the book *Inward Bound: Of Matter and Forces in the Physical World*. A while ago I had added the book to my reading list. I haven't read it yet, but you can check it in a library if you'll like it or not.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal thanks yeah I think this would be very interesting. Maybe I can find some biographies.

Comment: @KaanGüven thanks!